# Can I keep a REST web service in the same codebase as a regular web app

Tags: java, rest

I am working to create a web app. Simultaneously I am also developing a REST web service that will use the same codebase...What I want to know is, can I make the same codebase on a server function as base for both the web app and the web service. (In the web app a user can log in and perform operations while the web service is like an API).

Or do I need to keep 2 distinct code bases for the web app and the web service?

Also, I want the same web app to act as both producer and consumer of the web services...Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Technical a REST API is the same thing as the server side of a web application.

But if your REST API is accessed by third parties you might want to have a different versioning strategy then for your web app, so for anything of serious size I would probably separate those.

Sorry can't speak about the producer/consumer part of the question. Don't understand that part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it that way, but it means that you'll have to deploy the two together.  That might not always be desirable.

The alternative is to refactor the common classes into a third project, removing them from the app and the service.  Package those into a JAR that you add to both the REST service and the app, just as you would any other 3rd party JAR.  If you do it that way, you can deploy the two independently.  The cost is maintaining the common classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do both things from one codebase.. app and web service also, the complete game will be around URLs i.e. app URL and Web service URL..

And Yes it's possible, same web app to act as both producer and consumer.